# Map values in JPA in native query

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application with JPA.
I need to map a value in a query to entity.

Sample entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
@DynamicUpdate
public class Question{

 @Id
 @Column(nullable = false)
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @Lob
 private String description;

 @Transient
 private int noOfViews;

}
```

Sample Query

```
@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long> {

@Query(value = "select q.*,  2 NO_OF_VIEWS from questions q 
order by q.id DESC ", countQuery = "select count(*) from questions q order by q.id DESC " ,nativeQuery = true)
        Page<Question> findQuestions(Pageable pageable);

}
```

I need to set the value to noOfViews field. Any idea on this? 
Spring has RowMapper interface, but didn't find anything for spring boot.

Comment: In your `query` try using `AS` keyword for e.g. select q.*,  2 NO_OF_VIEWS `AS noOfViews` from questions q, JPA will auto map it since that is the Entity which you are returning and mentioning in JpaRepository

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at `SqlResultSetMapping` [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html)

Also there is a nice example by JPA project. [See this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/jpa21)

**Excerpt from above link.**

JPA 2.1 introduced the new SqlResultSetMapping type ConstructorResult which allows to map columns of a result set row to a constructor invocation which can be nicely used in combination with Value Objects.

TBH, I haven't tried this on @Transient fields but I have used @NamedNativeQuery with Projection DTO.